# UIScrollView zooming and GUI management

Tags: user-interface, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I would like to programmatically allow the user to zoom away from a current page inside of UIScrollView and present them with an overview of multiple pages. Then allow them to touch/choose one of the pages to zoom in.

I have multiple sub ViewControllers for each page. The important aspect is that each ViewController contains detailed information, so I want most of that information to be visible when they get a "birds eye view" of what's happening.

What's the best way to do this?

Additional detail: pretend each UIViewController has a UiTableView within them. There's 5,6,3,1,0,10 Cells in each of these (respectively) is there a way to show all Cells at once in the larger view?

Perhaps is there a way to screenshot the Views and present them as smaller objects?

Currently I have the UIPinchGestureRecognizer already working, just need a way to control the transition of these viewcontroller into the middle. Is there a way to screenshot each controller and transition to a different view for selection?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want it for a pdf viewer, then maybe you can implement something similar to this:
https://github.com/vfr/Reader

When corresponding button is pressed - modally rises up a gridview with smaller pages. When taped on any - it then opens that page.

If it's not about pdf viewer, and You still desire the pinch-zoom effect, then maybe you can implement two different views - where - on one will be in grid - all viewcontroller thumbnails, and on other - scrollview. When you pinch -zoom out - scrollview alpha changes to 0, while gridview list alpha changes to 1.  When taped on any viewcontroller thumbnail - alpha changes.

If You still want without fade-in fade-out, then it's even harder. On each pinch zoom movement, you need to recalculate each viewcontroller positions and sizes. and start moving them where they should be.

Hope that helps.. somehow..

Comment: I need to implement similar to the https://github.com/vfr/Reader but i need to set the same zooming effect on all the pages not only the current page...How to calculate and set the position and size of other viewcontroller